# Intersect two ordered lists

Tags: algorithm, list, intersection

Given two ordered array of strings, find a array that is the resulting intersection of them.

I currently have this algorithm, but it's not working.

Note: the atol() is valid because I'm certain that the arrays a and b will contain numbers as strings.

```
char** matchLists(char **a, char **b, int sizeA, int sizeB, int *lSize)
{
    char **list = malloc( sizeof(char *) );
    int pA = 0, pB = 0, listSize = 0;

    while(pA < sizeA && pB < sizeB)
    {

        if(atol(a[pA]) < atol(b[pB]))
        {

            pA++;

        }
        else if(atol(a[pA]) > atol(b[pB]))
        {

            pB++;

        }
        else
        {

            list = realloc(list, sizeof(char *) * (++listSize) );
            list[listSize-1] = b[pB];
            pA++;
            pB++;

        }


    }

    *lSize = listSize;

    return list;

}
```

Comment: " but it's not working" - please describe the error(s)

Comment: by "it's not working" I mean, the algorithm is not doing what it should do.

Comment: The initial `malloc` doesn't look necessary since you `realloc` every time just before adding an element to the list. You could simply initialize it to `NULL`.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What lists are you passing in? What is the output you get? How do you initialize the lists? Are you sure the lists are ordered? Do you have signed integer overflow? I wrote a test program for your function and it seems to pass the limited test cases I threw at it. Are you correctly indicating the length of the input lists? Are you sure realloc isn't failing sometime? Are you handling lSize correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using `char**` to store a string, this might be a confusion between the array pointer and pass-by-pointer issue, also starting listSize should be 1 not 0 ..

So your function should be like this ..

```
// only lSize here is pass-by-pointer
char* matchLists(char *a, char *b, int sizeA, int sizeB, int * lSize)
{
    char * list = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    int pA = 0, pB = 0, listSize = 1;

    while(pA < sizeA && pB < sizeB)
    {
        if(atol(a[pA]) < atol(b[pB]))
        {
            pA++;
        }
        else if(atol(a[pA]) > atol(b[pB]))
        {
            pB++;
        }
        else
        {
            list = (char*) realloc(list, sizeof(char)*(++listSize));
            list[listSize-1] = b[pB];
            pA++;
            pB++;
        }
    }

    *lSize = listSize;
    return list;
}
```

Call:

```
char a[256] = "This is not a test.";
char b[256] = "This is a test.";

int sizeA = 256;
int sizeB = 256;
int lSize = 1;

char* match = matchLists(a, b, sizeA, sizeB, &lSize);

printf("%s \n", match);
```